# .htaccess rewriterule all links

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to replace 'account/Username' / 'account/Username/' into 'account?account=Username'.

This is my current .htaccess, on the end of this script are 3 rules, I tried to create this rewriting by myself but not with any luck... Can you guys see what's the problem? (Sorry for being noob, I've no experience in .htaccess docs)

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?request=$1

ErrorDocument 500 /index.php?request=error
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?request=error
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?request=error

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?url\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://url.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteEngine Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} account
RewriteRule ^account/(.*)$ https://url.nl/account?account=$1
```

Comment: RewriteRule  works the other way around.

Comment: @PedroLobito More specific?

Comment: "__I'm trying to replace 'account/Username' / 'account/Username/' into 'account?account=Username'.__"  RewriteRule works the other way around

Comment: @PedroLobito So it won't be possible or?

Comment: Your wording is confusing and that's probably why no one can help you yet. **What do you want to see in the address bar of the browser**? Start there so it can be more clear of what you are looking for. Most people don't want query strings to show.

Comment: @PanamaJack url.nl/account/Username

Answer (score 0):

I am using a TPL engine, this is why it won't work.